# Промежуточная загрузка файла

Tags: javascript, html5, файлы, загрузка

на некоторых сайтах, при загрузке файла, файл "*скачивается в браузер*", после прохождения загрузки, файл отдается браузеру уже в скачанном ввиде. Как это происходит? Что за технология? И как такое сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Это новинки, поэтому осторожно отнеситесь к совместимости.**

`XMLHttpRequest` [может возвращать в качестве результата `Blob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Sending_and_Receiving_Binary_Data). Да, обычный XHR:

```js
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.open("GET", "/myfile.png", true);
oReq.responseType = "blob";

oReq.onload = function(oEvent) {
  var blob = oReq.response;
  //   ^ вот этот Блоб
};

oReq.send();
```

...за прогрессом скачивания можно следить, задав обработчик `onprogress`.

Из `Blob`а можно сделать URL:

```
objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

...и отдать его на "скачивание" любым удобным вам способом. Блоб существует исключительно на клиенте, и если существует, то уже целиком, поэтому "скачивание" блоба будет по факту сохранением уже загруженного его содержимого.

Блоб можно сформировать огромным количеством способов, XHR только один из них.