# Загрузка видео на сайт в виде Blob

Tags: javascript, html, потоки-данных, youtube, blob

Если посмотреть на youtube.com, то url у любого видео выглядит вот так: `blob:https://www.youtube.com/17c9289e-4450-4ea0-a0bd-56570172d62a`. Это говорит о том, что видео было загружено в виде бинарного объекта и обработано функцией `window.URL.createObjectURL()`.

Я не понимаю как они это делают со всем видео целиком, ведь оно большого размера, а url у видео не меняется до конца времени проигрывания (если плеер не решил поменять качество или сервер).

Вопрос заключается в том, как загружать видео на клиент в виде Blobа так, как делают это на youtube.com.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Промежуточная загрузка файла](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/501636/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b6%d1%83%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: @D-side, это же разные вещи, вы написали там про полную загрузку бинарника, здесь же происходит стриминг. Цитирую вас: "Блоб существует исключительно на клиенте, и если существует, то уже целиком", но видео начинает показываться гораздо раньше момента полной загрузки.

Comment: Fair enough. Голос отозвал. Но решение где-то там, недалеко, так что ссылку оставлю.

Comment: Вообще я перечитываю MDN по теме, и у меня складывается впечатление, что я там в ответе несколько неправ про то, что Blob обязательно должен быть уже загружен, чтобы сделать из него URL. Внушает подозрения [список событий в панели слева](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob). Но пока не проведу/увижу эксперимент, не берусь ничего утверждать: возможно, это просто ошибка.

Comment: @D-side, функции `window.URL.createObjectURL()` вообще по барабану, что в нее передаешь, она съедает абсолютно все, вот только, если она съела, то добавить в получившееся нечто (не знаю что это получается) уже никак.

Comment: Не, речь о том, что имеющийся объект блоба, теоретически, может знать, что он ещё не до конца загружен, и система придержит дальнейшее чтение, пока он не догрузится. Скорее всего, я несу чушь, но её можно проверить, посмотрев, в какой момент XHR2 выдаёт блоб  и даёт возможность на него сослаться. В начале загрузки файла или в конце. Все эксперименты, что я встречаю, показывают, что в конце, так что я не очень на это надеюсь.

Comment: Кажется, [вот вопрос об этом же на enSO](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18950869/2076787), советуют `fetch`. Надо покопаться поглубже.

Comment: Про `Blob` всё, что я вижу, пишут, что он всё же тело ответа сначала загружается целиком, и только потом получается блоб. Видимо, тут что-то более хитрое.

Comment: А... как на счёт [`MediaSource`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource#Examples)?

Comment: Интересный вопрос. Подгружаются кусочки по какому-то алгоритму. Попробовал покопаться что происходит после загрузки (брейкпойнт на `load`) - там десятки тысяч минифицированных строк, известно лишь что существующий контент и подгруженные кусочки преобразуются в `Int8Array`. Возможно дальше как-то склеиваются. Вопрос: Как же именно? А так - поддерживаю @D-side.

Comment: @Other по-моему, `MediaSource` и есть ответ, к нему **можно** приклеивать `ArrayBuffer`'ы (`appendBuffer`). И ютуб их точно использует: я почитал разминифицированный код, плохо, но видно, что используется именно он. К сожалению, написать нормальный ответ сейчас нет времени, но я уж найду .-.

Comment: @D-side, приклеивать-то можно, но просматривая исполнение кода, я не видел даже намёка на `MediaSource`. Хотя если Вы напишите ответ, где объясните что там происходит - буду очень рад.

Comment: @Other пока у меня не дошли руки, можете [изучить пример](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource#Examples). Да и даже если напишете ответ, я не обижусь :D Я довольно далёк от фронтендовых дел.

Comment: @D-side, как работает эта технология я знаю. Интересно что там ютьюбовцы нахимичили.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45318/discussion-between-d-side-and-other).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D-side, подсказал посмотреть в сторону [MediaSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaSource). Этот объект позволяет задать url объекта `video` как `window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource)`. Это позволяет задавать источник в виде Blob'а, но с одним важным свойством: мы можем догружать данные в `mediaSource`, например, при получении продолжения видео по AJAX или каким-либо другим способом.

Пример работы с MDN:

```
var video = document.querySelector('video');

var assetURL = 'frag_bunny.mp4';
var mimeCodec = 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"';

if ('MediaSource' in window && MediaSource.isTypeSupported(mimeCodec)) {
  var mediaSource = new MediaSource;
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
  mediaSource.addEventListener('sourceopen', sourceOpen);
} else {
  console.error('Unsupported MIME type or codec: ', mimeCodec);
}

function sourceOpen (_) {
  var mediaSource = this;
  var sourceBuffer = mediaSource.addSourceBuffer(mimeCodec);
  fetchData(assetURL, function (buf) {
    sourceBuffer.addEventListener('updateend', function (_) {
      mediaSource.endOfStream();
      video.play();
    });
    sourceBuffer.appendBuffer(buf);
  });
};
```

Метод рабочий, но есть свои приколы, например, 'video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"' - единственный майм кодек, который работает и в Chrome и в Mozilla. Если хочется работать с webm: 'video/webm; codecs="vp9,vorbis"' в Mozilla, то придется включать флаг в about:config, что не очень приятно для пользователя.